# Does Python's random module have a substitute for numpy.random.exponential?

Tags: python, random, numpy, exponential-distribution

I've been using Numpy's `numpy.random.exponential` function for a while. I now see that Python's `random` module has many functions that I didn't know about. Does it have something that replaces `numpy.random.exponential`? It would be nice to drop the `numpy` requirement from my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anything about `random.expovariate()` does not suit your needs, it's also easy to roll your own version:

```
def exponential(beta):
    return -beta * math.log(1.0 - random.random())
```

It seems a bit of an overkill to have a dependency on NumPy just for this functionality.

Note that this function accepts the mean `beta` as a parameter, as does the NumPy version, whereas the parameter `lambd` of `random.expovariate()` is the inverse of `beta`.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.expovariate

> **random.expovariate(lambd)**
>
> Exponential distribution. lambd is 1.0
>   divided by the desired mean. It should
>   be nonzero. (The parameter would be
>   called “lambda”, but that is a
>   reserved word in Python.) Returned
>   values range from 0 to positive
>   infinity if lambd is positive, and
>   from negative infinity to 0 if lambd
>   is negative.